# how to create a list of identical tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

folks,

I would like to create the following list, but instead of 3 repetitions, I want 12 repetitions in it. Is there a way to do it without type it 12 times explicitly? Thanks very much for your help.

```
[(0,pi), (0,pi), (0,pi)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [(0, pi) for i in range(12)]
```

The alternative (multiplying the list) may work for `tuple` objects because they are immutable, but you will rip hair out when you try it on `list` objects:

```
>>> pi = 3
>>> l = [[0, pi]] * 4
>>> l
[[0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3]]
>>> l[0][1] = 4
>>> l
[[0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4]]  # Wat
```

I personally stay away from that method for anything other than strings.

Answer (score 6):

This will work with tuples (but not recommended for lists):

```
  myl=[(0,pi)] * 12
```

gives `myl`

```
[(0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14),
 (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14)]
```

As @senderle mentions in a helpful comment below this is a good approach because tuples are *immutable*. This would *not* be a safe approach with lists as it could give unexpected results as can be seen in the example below.

**Tuples vs Lists:**

*With tuples:*

```
In [69]: myl=[(0,pi)] * 3
In [70]: myl
Out[70]: [(0, 3.14), (0, 3.14), (0, 3.14)]

In [71]: myl[0][0] = 55
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 myl[0][0] = 55
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

*With lists:*

```
In [72]: myl=[[0,pi]] * 3
In [73]: myl
Out[73]: [[0, 3.14], [0, 3.14], [0, 3.14]]

In [74]: myl[0][0] = 55
In [75]: myl
Out[75]: [[55, 3.14], [55, 3.14], [55, 3.14]]  # every list element changes!
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this approach works because tuples are immutable; with mutable objects it may produce unexpected results (unless you expect those results and they're desirable).

Comment: @Levon: (edits) Tuples are *immutable*. They cannot be modified after you create them.

Comment: @Blender Thanks Blender, that was some typo!!